# EntLib logging to category

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library

I'm using EntLib 4.1. I want to associate log entries with different categories. My categories will reflect various interesting bits of information such as the kind of context (say, "Batch" or "Online") and the functional area (say, "Invoice" or "Order").

I've done the logging code, but I think I'm doing something wrong in configuration. What I'm trying to achieve is to have all entries logged to category "Batch" end up in the event log called "Batch", and everything else in the Application log. (I have manually created a custom event log by this name.)

However, log entries with category Batch instead get logged to the Application log, and each entry contains the following preamble:

```
Message: Tracing to LogSource 'Batch' failed. Processing for other sources will continue. See summary information below for more information. Should this problem persist, stop the service and check the configuration file(s) for possible error(s) in the configuration of the categories and sinks.
```

EntLib config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
    <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true"
      defaultCategory="APPLICATION" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
        <listeners>
            <add source="Project II Logger" formatter="Text Formatter" log="Batch"
              machineName="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              name="BatchListener" />
            <add source="Project II Logger" formatter="Text Formatter" log="Application"
              machineName="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              traceOutputOptions="Callstack" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              name="DefaultListener" />
            <add fileName="c:\temp\trace.log" header="----------------------------------------"
              footer="----------------------------------------" formatter="ExceptionFormatter"
              listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              traceOutputOptions="Callstack" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              name="Exception TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
        <formatters>
            <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xD;&#xA;Message: {message}&#xD;&#xA;Category: {category}&#xD;&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xD;&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xD;&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xD;&#xA;Title:{title}&#xD;&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xD;&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xD;&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xD;&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xD;&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xD;&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xD;&#xA;ErrorMessages: {errorMessages}"
              type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              name="ExceptionFormatter" />
            <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xD;&#xA;Message: {message}&#xD;&#xA;Category: {category}&#xD;&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xD;&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xD;&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xD;&#xA;Title:{title}&#xD;&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xD;&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xD;&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xD;&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xD;&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xD;&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xD;&#xA;ErrorMessages: {errorMessages}"
              type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              name="Text Formatter" />
        </formatters>
        <categorySources>
            <add switchValue="All" name="APPLICATION">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="DefaultListener" />
                </listeners>
            </add>
            <add switchValue="All" name="Batch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="BatchListener" />
                </listeners>
            </add>
        </categorySources>
        <specialSources>
            <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
            <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
            <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="DefaultListener" />
                </listeners>
            </errors>
        </specialSources>
    </loggingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The message you are seeing in the application log indicates that logging to the Batch category failed.  Does it give you any other information like a stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I got a stack trace. But there was (and is) no reason to think the context in which I was logging had anything to do with the matter, so I didn't post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have not created the appropriate event log and/or event sources within that log.

The problem doesn't appear to be in the configuration file.

If you choose to set up the new log and such from a bat file or console app, make sure to run it under admin.

[creating log and source win 7](http://blog.kappasolutions.ca/blog/post/2010/07/04/How-To-Create-a-Custom-Event-Log-in-Windows-7.aspx)

Comment: Your answer is wrong, but I'll accept it. EntLib creates the logs and sources for you the first time something gets logged to the category, so you need not do that. The problem was related though: I tried to log to two different locations using the same source. This, it turns out is illegal in the windows eventlog model, and so only the nondescriptive error message can be blamed on EntLib. (I wanted the source to reflect.. the source. And it logs summary info about its activity to a centralized log but a more detailed trace elsewhere. Not allowed!)

Comment: The "Enterprises Library Logging" source is automatically registered, but no other custom sources.